# rotate image by pitch, roll, yaw with python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I want to rotate an image with given roll, pitch and yaw

Here is the example image

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

radian = math.radians(30)

def eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix(theta) :
    R_x = np.array([[1,                  0,                   0],
                    [0, math.cos(theta[0]), -math.sin(theta[0])],
                    [0,  math.sin(theta[0]), math.cos(theta[0]) ]])
    R_y = np.array([[math.cos(theta[1]), 0, math.sin(theta[1])],
                    [0,                  1,                  0],
                    [-math.sin(theta[1]), 0, math.cos(theta[1])]])
    R_z = np.array([[math.cos(theta[2]), -math.sin(theta[2]), 0],
                    [math.sin(theta[2]), math.cos(theta[2]),  0],
                    [0,                  0,                   1]])
    R = np.dot(R_z, np.dot( R_y, R_x ))
    return R

R = eulerAnglesToRotationMatrix((0,radian,0))
im = cv2.imread('yaw.png')
im = cv2.warpPerspective(im, R, (im.shape[1], im.shape[0]))
cv2.imshow('win', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

original image

[image]

below is the result rotated by pitch 30 degrees.

[image]

the result is wrong.

any idea?

Comment: An image is 2d, (pitch, yaw, roll) rotation makes sense for 3d objects, so what did you expect?

Comment: Do you get *wrong* results with small angles? Maybe it is because there is nothing to show at 30 degrees.

Comment: your matrices are for 3D. you can, however, rotate the 3D imaging plane, but for that you'll need the intrinsics in addition to those rotation matrices. Then it's something like NewImage = K*R*K^-1

Comment: just found out some examples https://github.com/eborboihuc/rotate_3d

Comment: This part is missing in your code: [3D to 2D](https://github.com/eborboihuc/rotate_3d/blob/614e0acf9b772007b517caca8921fe6167bab0d0/image_transformer.py#L97)

Comment: yup. just found out the repo code is the same as mine:)

Comment: can someone explain why we need this additional operation (https://github.com/eborboihuc/rotate_3d/blob/614e0acf9b772007b517caca8921fe6167bab0d0/image_transformer.py#L97)? I want to understand mathematical behind.

Comment: That is camera calibration matrix. This is the [first result from Google](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/camera-calibration.html#:~:text=The%20pinhole%20camera%20parameters%20are,the%20extrinsic%20and%20intrinsic%20parameters.). But the convention is different here (transpose).

Comment: You can do that using my ImageMagick script, 3Drotate, at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick. I use the terms, pan, tilt and roll. If you need it in Python, then use Python subprocess call to my bash unix shell script.

Comment: Did you get how to do it? @alec.tu
Can you write the edited or working version in the post